# How to use two checkboxes with a submit button to toggle visibility in javascript only

Tags: javascript

I am very, very, very new to javascript, but
essentially what I need to do is create two checkboxes linked to a submit button so that when you check one box and then hit submit it links to the CSS id and makes that part of the page visible and then when you uncheck the box and check the other box it links to the other CSS id and makes that part of the page visible

my idea is that I need two functions, one for each clicked checkbox linking each function to a single submit button

but how do I do this with only one submit button

and should I use functions or variables

how can I do this?

Comment: get the html element and modify its style attribute to change `display` to `none`. E.e. `node.style.display = 'none'`

Comment: "Should I use functions or variables" I'm guessing you'll need to use both. How about you try something, and if it doesn't work, as a question with the code you tried, in a [mcve]? See [ask].

Answer (score -1):

Not quite sure what your trying to achieve, but since your really new to JS I think something like this may work for you. I assume the styles are linked, you want one or the other. Best to use radio buttons if so.

```
Document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function(){

    if(document.getElementById('black').checked == true){
      document.getElementById('someDiv').style.display = "visible";
      document.getElementById('otherDiv').style.display = "none";
    }
    else{
    document.getElementById('otherDiv').style.display = "visible";
    document.getElementById('someDiv').style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

When you press the submit button, it calls a function, inside the function it checks to see which checkbox is selected. And displays and removes the elements you decide.
Hope this helps